# Why does null and true evaluate to null but null or true evaluates to true?

Tags: postgresql, null

Why does `null and true` evaluate to `null` in PostgreSQL but `null or true` evaluates to `true`?

I would have thought using `null` with `and` or `or` would've evaluated to `null` in both cases?

Comment: There are some truth tables and details at [NULL and three-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_(3VL))

Answer (score 1):

- `OR` is defined that if either side is `true` the expression evaluates to `true`.
- `AND` is defined such that if both sides are true boolean-3VL context, the expression evaluates to `true`;
- `null` is not true.